# Why Have index.php in URI in CodeIgniter Call

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

CodeIgniter gives this example Blog.php

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
                echo 'Hello World!';
        }
}
```

and calls it by

example.com/index.php/blog/

Question is why have index.php in the uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to know why there is the index.php in the URl?
There is a simple answer, any request under Codeigniter is given to the index.php which then resolves the controller. So however one does usally use mod_rewrite which masks the index.php.
The php interpreter itself does not have a concept of a controller, it only maps a URI to a file and gives it the post and get parameters.
So you need a file which which translates the URI in a controller call.

Answer (score 1):

The server (apache in your typical lamp stack) has to resolve to an executable php file. Without rewriting the only way to do that is by directly referencing a `.php` file (or a directory index file index like `index.html` or `index.php` etc). By default the path `example.com/blog/` would attempt to load the subdirectory `/blog`. To remove the `index.php` you need to enable url rewrite for your server. [CodeIgnitor has this well documented](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you dig into the index.php, you will know that Code Igniter needs to:
- Check system path
- Load constants
- Is the application able to write files? This is often used if you upload a file to the server
- Load core functions
- etc

Put in simply, the code igniter will load variables, functions, helpers, libraries, etc that might be used by you in the application

Comment: how do you remove index.php to create better urls?

Comment: The documentation already mentioned by [jpschroeder](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1267409/jpschroeder), it's [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html), just pay attention to section **Removing the index.php file**